# Push to Nuget.Server fails after upgrade to 2.0.1

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I upgraded a nuget.server that we use internally to 2.0.1 from 1.7. After upgrade push stopped working, it looks like it is working but the package is not pushed.

After I runt `nuget push ...` I get the message "Your package was pushed." but nothing is pushed and I don't get any error messages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with version 2.0.1 which I had installed. Downgrading to 2.0.0 made it all work just fine. Also, downloading the code and testing 2.1.0 worked as expected.